# Getting elements to fit from a vertical perspective when page is resized

Tags: css

How would I get the elements on my page to fit vertically when the page is resized?

Right now it works horizontally up until a certain point, but how would I do it for devices with different height orientations? It would be nice if the elements could dynamically resize or something.

**Code below:**

```
<div id="topPane">
        <h1 id="georgeLogo">Logo</h1>
    <div id="login">
        <div id="facebookLoginButton">Continue with Facebook</div>
        <br class="lb">
        <div class="center">or</div>
        <br class="lb">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address" required>
        <br class="lb">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br class="lb">
        <div id="standardLoginButton">Login</div>
        <br class="lb">
        <div id="copyright">© Copyright 2014</div>
    </div>


    <div id="bottomPane">
        <div id="loginPane">Login</div>
        <div id="registerPane">Sign Up</div>
    </div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bcbstn6/

Comment: Looks like you will need some media queries (or javascript) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Do you want to remove the padding/margin between the elements so all your items will fit on the screen? If so, you'll need JavaScript to detect the height of your window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use media queries, for example `min-height` and `max-height` in combination with
units like `vh`which are relative to the window height, example:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 550px) {
    #georgeLogo {
        font-size: 14vh;
    }
    #login {
        margin-top: 8vh;
    }
    .lb {
        line-height: 4vh !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 400px) {
    #georgeLogo {
        font-size: 14vh;
    }
    #login {
        margin-top: 2vh;
    }
    .lb {
        line-height: 1vh !important;
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h30c863e/1/

More information and examples here: http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/